# Selenium is unable to find element with data-testid attribute

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Trying to find the below element tried the following nothing works can anyone help.

```
<button data-testid="addToClientBasket" 
        class="sc-kfGgVZ kcCRfu">
    <span><i class="icon-Expand_Cross_30_by_30"></i>Add To Basket</span>
</button>
```

```
By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='addToClientBasket'");

By.xpath("//div[@id='root']/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/button/span";

By.cssSelector("button.sc-kfGgVZ.kcCRfu.added");

By.cssSelector("button.sc-kfGgVZ.kcCR");

By.cssSelector("button[class='sc-kfGgVZ kcCRfu']");
```

Comment: the element I am looking for is below.

Comment: <button data-testid="addToClientBasket" class="sc-kfGgVZ kcCRfu"><span><i class="icon-Expand_Cross_30_by_30"></i>Add To Basket</span></button>

Comment: Hve you tried selecting it by the class name ?

Comment: Can you give us the link to the website that has this web element?

Answer (score 2):

To identify the element with text as *Add To Basket* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-testid='addToClientBasket']>span>i.icon-Expand_Cross_30_by_30"));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='addToClientBasket']/span[contains(., 'Add To Basket')]"));
  ```

---

Presumably, moving ahead you will be invoking `click()`on the element and in that case ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[data-testid='addToClientBasket']>span>i.icon-Expand_Cross_30_by_30"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='addToClientBasket']/span[contains(., 'Add To Basket')]"))).click();
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below locators

```
button.sc-kfGgVZ.kcCRfu
button[data-testid="addToClientBasket"]

//button[@class='sc-kfGgVZ kcCRfu']
//button[@data-testid="addToClientBasket"]
```

And the reasons why the locators did not worked in your case

> By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='addToClientBasket'");
>
> > No closing bracket after attribute value
>
> By.xpath("//div[@id='root']/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/button/span";
>
> > Not sure if your element path is correct
>
> By.cssSelector("button.sc-kfGgVZ.kcCRfu.added");
>
> > There is no button with `added` classname
>
> By.cssSelector("button.sc-kfGgVZ.kcCR");
>
> > There is no button with the specified classes combination
>
> By.cssSelector("button[class='sc-kfGgVZ kcCRfu']");
>
> > those are 2 classes so you have to replace the white-space with `.`